# How to use System::Guid and custom enum in std::pair?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to to create a vector of of std::pairs in visual c++ with common language runtime support enabled. 
The pairs should contain `System::Guid` and `MyEnum`. However I am unable to get the syntax right and keep getting compile time errors. What am I doing wrong?

**I created a minimal example below:**

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

enum class MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    error1,
    error2,

};


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<System::Guid, MyEnum>> errorList;
    std::pair<System::Guid, MyEnum> pair(System::Guid(), MyEnum::None);
    //errorList.push_back(pair);
}
```

If I try to compile this code, I get the following error message

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Playground, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c1xx : warning C4199: two-phase name lookup is not supported for C++/CLI, C++/CX, or OpenMP; use /Zc:twoPhase-
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\type_traits(831): error C2059: syntax error: '{'
1>c:\users\32000\source\repos\playground\playground\main.cpp(18): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_constructible<System::Guid,System::Guid>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\type_traits(831): note: see reference to variable template 'const bool conjunction_v<std::is_constructible<System::Guid,System::Guid>,std::is_constructible<enum MyEnum,enum MyEnum>,std::negation<std::conjunction<std::is_convertible<System::Guid,System::Guid>,std::is_convertible<enum MyEnum,enum MyEnum> > > >' being compiled
1>c:\users\32000\source\repos\playground\playground\main.cpp(16): fatal error C1075: '{': no matching token found
1>Done building project "Playground.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I use std::make_pair instead of the constructor:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

enum class MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    error1,
    error2,

};


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<System::Guid, MyEnum>> errorList;
    //std::pair<System::Guid, MyEnum> pair(System::Guid(), MyEnum::None);
    auto pair2 = std::make_pair(System::Guid(), MyEnum::None);
    //errorList.push_back(tuple);
}
```

I get no `matching overloaded function found`.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Playground, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c1xx : warning C4199: two-phase name lookup is not supported for C++/CLI, C++/CX, or OpenMP; use /Zc:twoPhase-
1>c:\users\32000\source\repos\playground\playground\main.cpp(19): error C2672: 'std::make_pair': no matching overloaded function found
1>c:\users\32000\source\repos\playground\playground\main.cpp(19): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'std::pair<_Unrefwrap_helper<decay<_Ty>::type>::type,_Unrefwrap_helper<decay<_Ty2>::type>::type> std::make_pair(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&)'
1>c:\users\32000\source\repos\playground\playground\main.cpp(19): note: With the following template arguments:
1>c:\users\32000\source\repos\playground\playground\main.cpp(19): note: '_Ty1=System::Guid'
1>c:\users\32000\source\repos\playground\playground\main.cpp(19): note: '_Ty2=MyEnum'
1>Done building project "Playground.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` may be messing you up.

Comment: The syntax itself looks fine: https://godbolt.org/z/r4TE5X. The syntax error in `type_traits` kinda looks like your compiler is too old for the standard library you're using (or vice versa?). Thanks to the warning about two-phase lookup we know that you are compiling either with C++/CLI, C++/CX or OpenMP (I would guess it's C++/CLI), could you please add an appropriate tag for whichever it is?

Comment: @MaxLanghof I am compiling with`/clr`. Thanks to your comment I added `/Zc:twoPhase-` to suppress the warning. I am now getting a more understandable error message. 

`error C3265: cannot declare a managed 'first' in an unmanaged 'std::pair<System::Guid ^,MyEnum>`

**Edit:** I made a mistake, the text aboe maybe is not correct. I am investigating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All problems I described above originated from the fact, that I tried to mix c++ with c++/cli.

I wanted to use a std::pair System::Guid is not native. 
While it is possible to mix native with non native c++ in my case the easiest thing to  do was to stay with c++/cli.

Instead of using a vector I am using System::List. Instead of using a std::pair 
I am directly convert my guid and error code into a string.

The solution that worked for looked something like this.

**Note:** The code below works as part of a larger project. I do not maintain the whole project by my own. Therefore there is a chance that this code does not work 
for you, because it needs compiler options, which are already set in my project.

**Collection Errorcodes:**

```
List<String^> errorList;
System::String^ errorString = String::Format("Id: {0} | errorReason: {1} ", System::Guid, MyEnum::None); 
errorList.Add(errorString);
```

**Iterating over the errors:**

```
System::String^ errorMessage = "Received corrupt data | ";
int index = 1;
for each(auto errorGuids in errorList)
{
   errorMessage += index + ". " + errorGuids + " | ";
   index++;
}
```